# Java graphics2D rotating

Tags: java, rotation, graphics2d

I'm making a game in Java, but I'm having a problem when rotating an image.

When I'm rotating an image using graphics2D, the image's X and Y is changing on the screen. Still when I'm getting the image's X and Y, the value is the same as it was before being rotated. On the screen however, it's displayed on another position.

Anyone who knows a method or formula that can get the image back to the original position?

Comment: You probably need to supply a anchor point around which the image can be rotated

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the point of rotation to the middle of your image (or whatever object you're rotating).

For example, if the image you want to rotate is 20x20px then the point of rotation should be at (X_POS + 10, Y_POS + 10);

X_POS and Y_POS are the coordinates of the upper left vertex of your image on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when you draw an image you specify a top/left coordinate to paint the image. However as your rotate a non-rectangular image the size of the image will change and so the x/y location will change.

So instead you need to think about rotating the image about its center point. So for every rotation you need to recalculate the x/y location relative to the center.

In the example below the image will be rotated around the point (300, 300):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class Rotation3 extends JPanel
{
    private Icon icon;
    private RotatedIcon rotated;
    private int degrees;

    public Rotation3(Image image)
    {
        icon = new ImageIcon( image );
        rotated = new RotatedIcon(icon, 0);
//      rotated.setCircularIcon( true );
        setDegrees( 0 );
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(600, 600) );
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // translate x/y so Icon rotated around a specific point (300, 300)

        int x = 300 - (rotated.getIconWidth() / 2);
        int y = 300 - (rotated.getIconHeight() / 2);
        rotated.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);

        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(295, 295, 10, 10);
    }

    public void setDegrees(int degrees)
    {
        this.degrees = degrees;
        rotated.setDegrees(degrees);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
//                  String path = "dukewavered.gif";
                    String path = "lunch75.jpg";
                    ClassLoader cl = Rotation3.class.getClassLoader();
                    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(Rotation3.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
                    final Rotation3 r = new Rotation3(bi);

                    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 360, 0);
                    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
                        {
                            int value = slider.getValue();
                            r.setDegrees( value );
                        }
                    });

                    JFrame f = new JFrame();
                    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    f.add(new JScrollPane(r));
                    f.add(slider, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                    f.pack();
                    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    f.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch(IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note:

This example uses the [Rotated Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/) class since this class manages the changing dimensions of the image as it is rotated.

Also, if you use a "circular" icon then you can use the `setCircularIcon(true)` and the size will not be recalculated, so you can specify the x/y values as the top/left.